# apt-get, aptitude package version

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, aptitude

How can I find out package versions available from repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a command like `apt-cache show package`.

You could also just look at the repository.

- http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4):

`apt-cache policy $PACKAGE` shows every packageversion available for installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try apt-show-versions.

Comment: Note, `apt-show-version` may not be installed on all distributions by default.

Answer (score 0):

For installed packages:

```
dpkg-query -l apache2
```

For packages available via apt:

```
apt-cache search ^apache2$
```

Answer (score 0):

Aptitude is Debian's current recommended package manager (see Lenny Release Notes) and amongst other things is great for searching available and installed packages.

e.g.

aptitude search ~npackage_name_regex~dtext_in_description

See section 2.2.6. in the Reference Manual:
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch02.en.html#_basic_package_management_operations

However, use 'apt-cache policy' to show package versions.